# How to convert float value to date9 format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandasql

Basically i am sas developer.
As of now i am doing sas2python migrations.
Before reading to pandas dataframe i have two columns ie,

```
DATE          NAME
01JAN1988     VARUN
11JAN1999     THARUN
```

After reading to pandas dataframe the `DATE` columns is automatically read as `float` values. Now I need to show it as `DATE` Columns  as date9 format 
Could you please provide the steps

Comment: Yeah, I've faced that issue. Are you reading the sas7bdat file using `read_sas()`?

Comment: Can you add details about how you're reading the data, and what the data looks like in pandas? Edit the question to add these.

Comment: Basically, what I did was add the float to `1960-01-01` (SAS Epoch date) to get the required date.

Comment: i am using read_sas method to read sas datasets in pandas

Comment: Do you mind adding all details to your question. Would help us answer in one go if we understand the issue in one.

Comment: Before reading to pandas dataframe
DATE          NAME
01JAN1988     VARUN
11JAN1999     THARUN
samething i need to get date columns in date9format after reading pandas dataframe
As of now i have done like
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_sas(dataset,format=sas7bdat)
need inputs after the above step

Answer (score 0):

you can use apply function to convert the values into date objects and datetime module to covert them:

```
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%d%b%Y').date())
```

Output:

```
        DATE    NAME

0   1988-01-01  VARUN

1   1999-01-11  THARUN
```